# Can't get VPNSecure installed/running correctly on RPi3B with Raspbian

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, vpn

I'm trying to set my RPi 3B running Raspbian up with a VPN and I already subscribe to VPNSecure so I attempted to install it using the Linux instructions here: https://support.vpnsecure.me/articles/getting-started/linux-vpnsecure-client-install using the 64-bit installer (32-bit wouldn't work and kept giving an error).  It seemed to work fine and put an icon in the Start menu under Accessories but every time I attempt to run it, it opens a dialog stating that it needs permission to run and requiring a password. Once I put the password in, I get an hourglass for a few seconds and then nothing happens... It never goes anywhere or does anything. Trying to run it via command line also throws an error and does nothing:

```
/etc/vpnsecure/vpnsecure: 1: /etc/vpnsecure/vpnsecure: ELF: not found
/etc/vpnsecure/vpnsecure: 2: /etc/vpnsecure/vpnsecure: : not found
/etc/vpnsecure/vpnsecure: 7: /etc/vpnsecure/vpnsecure: Syntax error: end of file unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I'm fairly unfamiliar with Linux and have done ok up until now. Has anyone has success getting this installed on your system? And if I'm completely in the wrong area can you please help me figure out how to completely uninstall and start from scratch? I'm not great with all the command line stuff and keeping up with it so I prefer the GUI approach for this if at all possible. I greatly appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raspbian is a 32 bit operating system. Executable files on Linux have the ELF format (similar to EXE files on MS Window$). The error message `ELF: not found` is typical if the operating system cannot find that a file is executable, in particular it isn't a 32 bit program. You should use the 32 bit installer and fix the error it is giving.

**Update:** in respect to the comment getting "Exec format error"
I have checked the available installer you have given with the link in your question. You can download them with:

```
# 32 bit version
rpi ~$ sudo curl --insecure -o vpnsecure-2.0.8-ia32.tar.gz https://downloads.vpnsecure.me/vpnsecure-2.0.8-ia32.tar.gz
# 64 bit version
rpi ~$ sudo curl -o vpnsecure-2.1.7.tar.gz https://downloads-us.vpnsecure.me/vpnsecure-2.1.7.tar.gz
```

Extract the excecutable installer:

```
rpi ~$ tar -xvf vpnsecure-2.0.8-ia32.tar.gz vpnsecure-2.0.8/vpnsecure
rpi ~$ tar -xvf vpnsecure-2.1.7.tar.gz vpnsecure-2.1.7/vpnsecure
```

Check their file format:

```
rpi ~$ file vpnsecure-2.0.8/vpnsecure
vpnsecure-2.0.8/vpnsecure: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=00902f79beef7f688bf765c81ad98323be1f3ed6, stripped

rpi ~$ file vpnsecure-2.1.7/vpnsecure
vpnsecure-2.1.7/vpnsecure: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, stripped
```

As you can see your favorite program does support **Intel 80386**, resp. **x86-64** but does not support Raspberry Pi that has an **ARM** processor.

Comment: Thank you, I'll figure out how to uninstall the 64 bit and get the 32 bit installed correctly.

Comment: when I try the 32bit install I get errors, are you able to offer any insight?     install32: line 12: Installation: command not found
install32: line 13: ./vpnsecure: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Comment: @Tommy I have updated the answer.

Comment: yeah in searching around I discovered the same problem.  Thank you for your help!  I'm looking into other solutions for now.

Comment: I can not download the 32 bit version:

 $ sudo curl --insecure -o vpnsecure-2.0.8-ia32.tar.gz https://downloads.vpnsecure.me/vpnsecure-2.0.8-ia32.tar.gz
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (35) error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol

Comment: @RonK. Comments are not a good place for help. You should create a new question. You can use a link to this question for reference.

Comment: Broken instructions.